# Создать шаблон контролов для многократного добавления на форму winForm С#

Tags: c#, шаблоны, формы

помогите разобраться возможно ли задуманное и если да - что гуглить :) 
Вопрос: есть форма на которой должно быть, например, **4 одинаковых блока** (на рисунке groupBox-ы) - в которых **набор контролов** (кнопка, датагрид и текстбокс), логика в блоках одинаковая. Когда таких блоков 4е - еще куда ни шло, но если надо 10, то создавать весь код вручную напряжно и, наверно, не разумно - можно ли создать шаблон (класс что ли?) и потом в основной форме создавать экземпляры - типа:

```
 List<Шаблон_контролов> ControlTemplate = new List<Шаблон_контролов>
        {
            new Шаблон_контролов { передать параметр координат левого верхнего угла },
            new Шаблон_контролов { - //- },
            new Шаблон_контролов { - //- }
        };
```

и можно ли потом обращаться к контролам шаблона например так:

```
ControlTemplate[i].textBox1.text = "12345qwe";
ControlTemplate[i].dataGridView_preview1.DataSource = qwert;
```

заранее спасибо, не пинайте пожалуйста)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Составные элементы управления](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/varieties-of-custom-controls#composite-controls)

Comment: tym32167, спасибо за наводку, нашел видео - где немного понятней как работать с составными элементами https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5L_q_jI494